# Local development with Django

Tags: django, localhost, dnsmasq

I am using dnsmasq on my mac in order to force the domain I'm developing for (example.com) to resolve to localhost.

This means that if I go to http://example.com:8000, it uses the local development server, which is what I want.

But it also means that if I try and go to the real example.com, that doesn't resolve to the real site, obviously - it's using localhost.

Is there a way for me to develop locally with port 8000 but also be able to view the real site (without a port - or port 80)?

EDIT:

Everyone seems a bit confused about what I'm trying to do here so let me explain.

I'm trying to develop a site so that it can display different content on any subdomain of example.com. In order to do that, I need to use the Sites framework without setting SITE_ID and let the Sites framework figure out the Site by looking at the domain in the request.

That means that I can't use localhost:8000 when testing as there is no Site with localhost as the domain. I need to use example.com:8000 (or site1.example.com:8000, site2.example.com:8000, sitewhatever.example.com) instead.

But in order to do that, I need to point example.com at localhost in the hosts file. However, that means that the real example.com doesn't resolve any more.

That's what I'm trying to figure out here.

Comment: why do you need to force the domain at all? (Whats wrong with `localhost:8000`?)

Comment: I'm developing my app locally - if I don't make the domain point at localhost, it'll resolve to the IP of the real domain, not my mac.

Comment: But *why*? `runserver` does a great job at providing a tool to develop locally without any crazy dns overhaul

Comment: I think the question is `no`, you can not have both local and "real" server at the same time. To have a possibility to view real site u have to deploy your code on the remote server.

Comment: I'm using runserver. But then I need to use the full domain to test it, rather than just localhost. This is because I need to be able to use several different subdomains on the main domain, each serving different content.

Comment: @Chiefir I know I have to deploy to see the real site. I've done that. But if I want to make changes locally (develop the site further) AND see the existing live site, how would I do that?

Comment: @bodger - u should push your changes to git and pull them from there. or you can use *SFTP* - some IDEs have it built in (like Pycharm) - you can connect to your server code directly.

Comment: @bodger - but still that will be only *server instance* of your site, it wont be both remote and local.

Comment: @Chiefir Maybe I'm not making myself clear. The site is already deployed. I can see it if I go to example.com. But I need to make changes locally to develop it further. This means I need to use example.com:8000. In order to do that, I need to point example.com at localhost. But that means I cannot see example.com any more.

Comment: what is in your ALLOWED_HOSTS setting? you can access your site via any of that *ip* or *domain*.

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS is set to ['.example.com']. That's not the problem, I can assure you.

Comment: Like everyone else, I am finding it impossible to understand what your problem actually is. Why do you need to pretend that your localhost is example.com? Why can't you just use localohst?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Apologies if it's not very clear. I am using the Sites framework (without SITE_ID) so that I can have site1.example.com, site2.example.com etc. When I'm developing locally, I need to use the real subdomains to test each one, because it looks the Site up via the domain in the request.